# Call function javascript first second

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make it so that on a first click i call one function for javascript, and on a second click i call another function for javascript. How can that be?

Basically i press on this image, it calls this function, if i press it again it calls another function. First then second.

Using html

Comment: It should go from first to second back to first back to second click and so on

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
  <script>
    var clicked = false;

    function doSomething()
   {
      if(clicked)
     {
       alert(2); 

     }
    else
    {
       alert(1); 

    }
   clicked = !clicked;
}
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="hello" onClick="doSomething();">Hello World</p>
</body>
```

See exmple here http://jsbin.com/uzivuj

Comment: How can i make it rever back to 1 on third click?

Comment: see updated code here http://jsbin.com/uzivuj/2/edit, I updated the code to show this

Comment: @SachinKumar did you try the example at https://jsbin.com/uzivuj/2/

Answer (score 2):

First, you mean JavaScript.

Basically, in the first event handler, you want to remove it, then assign the new one:

```
function foo()
{
   // Other work
   this.removeEventListner("click", foo, false);
   this.addEventListener("click", bar, false);
}

function bar()
{

}

element.addEventListener("click", foo, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will alternate between calling `first()` and `second()` each time the button is clicked.

```
<input type="button" id="mybutton" value="Click me" />

<script>

    function first() { alert("first"); }
    function second() { alert("second"); }

    var toggleFlag = true;

    $("#mybutton").click(function() {
        toggleFlag ? first() : second();
        toggleFlag = !toggleFlag;
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you

```
<a href=# onclick="onClickEvent()">
    <img src="[Src]" width="208" height="58" >
</a>


var count = 0;

function function1(){
    alert("Function 1");
    count++;
}

function function2(){
     alert("Function 2");
     count = 0;
}

function onClickEvent(){
     if(count ==0){
         function1();
     }else{
         function2();
     }
}
```

Comment: Does this repeat to 1 then2  then 1 then 2?

Comment: Yes. First Click- Call Function1. Second Click-Call Function2. Third click-Call Function1.

Comment: Is there a way to specify it under one function like the post above by Daveo? So i can just call one function

Answer (score -3):

Try This

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mybutton").click(function(){
            $("p").toggle();
        });`enter code here`
    });
    </script>

    <h2>This is a heading</h2>

    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>

    <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="Click me to show" />
```